# Error attaching databse - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to attach a database created in SQL Server 2000, 2005 or 2008 (I don't remember where it was created) to a SQL Server 2014 instance or higher?

When I'm trying in SQL Server 2014 Enterprise, I get this error:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Error de Adjuntar base de datos para Servidor 'DESKTOP-CLR61ND'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Excepción al ejecutar una instrucción o un proceso por lotes Transact-SQL. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Database 'Logistica' cannot be upgraded because its non-release version (539) is not supported by this version of SQL Server. You cannot open a database that is incompatible with this version of sqlservr.exe. You must re-create the database.
>
> Could not open new database 'Logistica'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted. (Microsoft
> SQL Server, Error: 950)

Does anyone can tell me how to upgrade those database to 2014 or higher?

Answer (score 0):

> I dont remember where it was created) in a SQL Server 2014 or higher?

It does not matter what it was created with - if you attach it to a SQL Server that is a little more modern, it gets updated.

> Is there a way to attach a database created in SQL 2000, 2005 or 2008 (I dont remember
> where it was created) in a SQL Server 2014 or higher?

Yes. STEP BY STEP. Backup/restore 2 versions at a time. 2000 is so old that there is no support anymore. Go step by step.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33418/use-older-versions-of-sql-server-databases-with-2012/33420

Comment: I dont have an .bak file for those database,  i have only data and log files, as i understood i need a .bak

Comment: @CristhianCobeñasHuamani Nothing anyone can do to help you. You will need an older version (2008 R2 or earlier) of sql server that can attach those files successfully. That will upgrade them to a version that can then be attached to your 2012 server instance.

Comment: So i should to upgrade first to SQL 2008 then i can upgrade it to 2012 or higher?

Comment: Yes - but there is nothing to upgrade is there? You just need access to the older version (and edition possibly). It sounds like you don't have the old database server anymore - just the old database files. You will need the install media to create a new instance. Once you do that, you attach the old files. If that works, I suggest you first make a backup. Then repeat that process for the final version/edition you want to actually use.